# How to get current page number and total page number in ui-grid?

Tags: angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

It took me a lot of time on how to find current page number and total page number in ui-grid, I want to use it to change the grid's height of last page. So I want to write it down.

Answer (score 0):

The key point is to use `gridApi` to captuer the change of page number:

```
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
      gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged($scope, function (newPage, pageSize) {
      paginationOptions.pageNumber = newPage;
      paginationOptions.pageSize = pageSize;
      $scope.pageSize = pageSize;
      $scope.currentPage = newPage;
      $scope.totalPage = Math.ceil($scope.gridOptions.totalItems/$scope.pageSize);
      });
   }
```

The whole version can see [here in Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/np6y6rgN1ThnT0ZqyJeo?p=preview)